# Stream Segmentation: Which browsers support it?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, m3u

Apple has a spec for using .m3u as a playlist file of .ts video segments. I understand it works on iOS devices and OSX Safari. Is it supported by any other browsers? If not, are there any other methods of segmenting a video into parts for independent download and playing?

Here's the apple spec for video segmentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Is it supported by any other browsers?"*: **No**

*"If not, are there any other methods of segmenting a video into parts for independent download and playing?"*:  [Adobe is making an effort to do something similar](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/dynstream_advanced_pt1.html) but I have yet to see it in production anywhere.  They probably will not be compatible, at least at first.

CODECs matter.  Hence, FireFox will likely never natively support it as Mozilla hates h.264.  I'm also skeptical about native Chrome support too, but time will tell.